c# maui ssl certificate check error "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
In our .NET MAUI application for android and iOS I have to validate the SSL certificate before calling our WCF WebService.
When I do this the certificate chain build result is false with error "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".
Here is my validation method:
 internal class Validator : X509CertificateValidator
 {
     public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
     {
         if (certificate == null)
         {
             throw new ArgumentNullException("MediApp WebService certificate for validation is NULL!");
         }

         X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();

         bool chainBuildResult = chain.Build(certificate);

         if (chainBuildResult == false)
         {
             if (chain.ChainStatus != null)
             {
                 foreach (var singleStatus in chain.ChainStatus)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(singleStatus.Status + ": " + singleStatus.StatusInformation);
                 }
             }

             throw (new Exception("SSL certificate is not valid"));
         }
     }
 }   

And it is initialized for using by:
 client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(Url);

 if (Url.StartsWith("https://"))
 {
     actualHttpBinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
     actualHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;


     client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication();
     client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
     client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication.RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
     client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication.CustomCertificateValidator = new MediApp.Maui.SSL.Validator();
 }

The certificate which shall be validated is correct, so I expect an result of true for the chain build.
Any suggestions?

"is correct" what do you mean correct? Do you know that the server trusts the issuer of the client certificate?

Yes, when I check it wil an online SSL Validator it says everything is fine.

How do you validate a client certificate using an online validator, normally those only work with HTTP server certificates? And which validator are you using? Are you sure it's checking the trust chain, why would its trust store necessarily be the same as your server's store?

I put the URL to the site here https://www.geocerts.com/ssl-checker and get "ll of the correct Intermediate CA Certificates are installed. Your SSL certificate is installed correctly and should be supported in all the major web browsers without problems." In browser its ok too.

That's checking the server certificate, it appears your code is trying to verify the client certificate, which is not the same thing. Where does the client certificate come from, who is the issuer?

I want to validate the server certificate, its from the server,, for testing I do the download by myself and try the validation, I got the same error as mentioned above.

client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate unsurprisingly refers to validation of the client certificate by the server. The server doesn't need to validate its own certificate, the client does that. I think you are somewhat confused what's going on here. Authentication in this case is being done mutually (both client and server pass a certificate). The server's certificate appears to be trusted globally, but the client's certificate is not. You need to investigate what certificate the client is passing, and why it's not trusted.

Maybe it is a misunderstood, this code is called in a client MAUI application on an android smartphone. This client contacts a https WCF side. The https SSL certificate shall be validated on the client side for security reasons.
